# Replace Fragment with another on back button

Tags: android, fragment, back-button

I'm trying to override the Back Button because it's closing my app when I push on, I have different Fragments:

- Fragment A: Index (When I press back button, it's will close the app)
- Fragment B (When I press back button it will go back to the Fragment A)
- Fragment C (When I press back button it will go back to the Fragment A)

And I have my Main Activity: It manage my Fragments (for have a Navigation Drawer).

I found many posts on this but I can't implement them:

On Fragment B for exemple:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment f = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentb); // get the fragment that is currently loaded in placeholder
    Object tag = f.getTag();
    // do handling with help of tag here
    // call super method
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

It say cannot resolve onBackPressed() and getSupportFragmentManager(), I think I don't use the method correctely, so how to do ?

### Activity:

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentDrawer.FragmentDrawerListener {

    private static String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private FragmentDrawer drawerFragment;

    //Initialisation de l activite avec les donnees necessaires
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        drawerFragment = (FragmentDrawer)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
        drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), mToolbar);
        drawerFragment.setDrawerListener(this);
        // Affichage de la navigation
        displayView(0);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        //Ajout des items
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerItemSelected(View view, int position) {
        displayView(position);
    }

    private void displayView(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        String title = getString(R.string.app_name);
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new Accueil();
                title = getString(R.string.title_accueil);
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new NosOffres();
                title = getString(R.string.title_nosoffres);
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new DemandeGratuite();
                title = getString(R.string.title_demandegratuite);
                break;
            case 3:
                fragment = new ContactezNous();
                title = getString(R.string.title_contact);
                break;
            case 4:
                fragment = new Actualites();
                title = getString(R.string.title_actu);
                break;
            case 5:
                fragment = new MentionsLegales();
                title = getString(R.string.title_mentions);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            // libelle du toolbar
            TextView titlet;
            titlet = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar_title);
            titlet.setText(title);
            titlet.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/GothamBook.ttf"));
        }
    }
}
```

### @jujyfruits

I tryedbut it doesn't work:

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        Fragment myFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.demande_gratuite);
        if (myFragment != null && myFragment.isVisible()) {
            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Reset...");
            alertDialog.setMessage("test");
            alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                }
            });
            alertDialog.show();
        }
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

### @AutonomousApps

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentDrawer.FragmentDrawerListener {

    private static String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private FragmentDrawer drawerFragment;

    //Initialisation de l activite avec les donnees necessaires
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        drawerFragment = (FragmentDrawer)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
        drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), mToolbar);
        drawerFragment.setDrawerListener(this);
        // Affichage de la navigation
        displayView(0);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        //Ajout des items
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerItemSelected(View view, int position) {
        displayView(position);
    }

    private void displayView(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        String title = getString(R.string.app_name);
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new Accueil();
                title = getString(R.string.title_accueil);
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new NosOffres();
                title = getString(R.string.title_nosoffres);
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new DemandeGratuite();
                title = getString(R.string.title_demandegratuite);
                break;
            case 3:
                fragment = new ContactezNous();
                title = getString(R.string.title_contact);
                break;
            case 4:
                fragment = new Actualites();
                title = getString(R.string.title_actu);
                break;
            case 5:
                fragment = new MentionsLegales();
                title = getString(R.string.title_mentions);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("name");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            // libelle du toolbar
            TextView titlet;
            titlet = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar_title);
            titlet.setText(title);
            titlet.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/GothamBook.ttf"));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        FragmentManager mgr = getSupportFragmentManager();
        if (mgr.getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }else{
             mgr.popBackStack();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your **activity** has the fragment manager (and I think also the `onBackPressed()` call), not the fragment.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce But if I put     Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
    } On MainActivity how I m gonna configure back button for the different Fragments ?

Comment: @benjy care to post the activity code?

Comment: @benjy as the two answers say, you did not override onBackPressed in your activity.

Comment: @milez I did here:     Override
    public void onBackPressed(){ }

Comment: @benjy it is not in the activity code you posted?

Comment: I think thats me I don't really understand sorry, Look my edited response to jujyfruits, thats not the good way to overrite ?

Comment: The code has to be placed to your activity  class

Comment: @milez  that what i did, its my Main Activity

Comment: Your if-statement is wrong. `myFragment.isVisible()` will return `false` because the fragment you want to return to is NOT visible. You need to use `addToBackStack(String)` and then it's easier to check `getBackStackEntryCount()` and perform your operations there. See my answer for more details.

Comment: I believe that the reason you have to tap 'back' twice, even when your backstack entry count is 0, is because you are *always* calling `addToBackStack()` when you do fragment transactions. The very *first* transaction should *not* be added to the backstack. I explain in my revised answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what I use when navigating between fragments:

**MainActivity.java:**

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // note: you can also use 'getSupportFragmentManager()'
    FragmentManager mgr = getFragmentManager();
    if (mgr.getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {
        // No backstack to pop, so calling super
        super.onBackPressed();
    } else {
        mgr.popBackStack();
    }
}
```

**EDIT the second:** Please note that you ONLY want to call `super.onBackPressed()` if you haven't already handled it (by, for example, popping the fragment manager's backstack).

For that to work, you have to add new fragments to your `FragmentManager`'s backstack (`addToBackStack()`). For example (also in **MainActivity.java**):

```
private void displayView(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = ...; // YOUR CODE HERE
    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);

        // ADD THIS LINE
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("name"); // name can be null

        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        // libelle du toolbar
        TextView titlet;
        titlet = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar_title);
        titlet.setText(title);
        titlet.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/GothamBook.ttf"));
    }
}
```

**EDIT the third (7/28):** In your `onCreate(Bundle)` method, you do your very first fragment transaction by calling your `displayView(int)` method. `displayView(int)` *always* adds its fragment transactions to the backstack. This is not what you want. The very *first* fragment transaction should use `fragmentTransaction.**add**(int, Fragment)` and should *not* call `addToBackStack(String)`. Every transaction *after* the first should call `fragmentTransaction.**replace**(int, Fragment)` and *should* call `addToBackStack(String)`. The reason for this is that you *first* transaction is basically "adding" a fragment (your UI) to an empty container (it is not "replacing" another fragment). When this transaction is on the backstack, that means that the empty-container state is *also* on the backstack. So when you pop that last transaction, it displays a blank UI.

**EDIT the first:** When you call [`addToBackStack(String name)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#addToBackStack(java.lang.String)) on a [`FragmentTransaction`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html) object (which you obtain by calling [`getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#beginTransaction())), then you are adding a `FragmentTransaction` to your `FragmentManager`s 'backstack'. What my code does is check the *size* of the backstack by calling [`getFragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#getBackStackEntryCount()). If that number is greater than zero, then we know we have `FragmentTransaction`s on the backstack. In such a case, you can call [`getFragmentManager.popBackStack()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#popBackStack()), which will pop the last transaction off the backstack--in other words, returning your app to the last Fragment that was on display.

If the backstack entry county equals 0, then that means you're at your Fragment A, and you should instead call `super.onBackPressed()`, and this will cause the app to exit.

Comment: I don't understand the second code what I have to do in... and what is FragmentManager's backstack

Comment: see my additional explanation. Let me know if you need more information. You should definitely be reading the docs and the Google developer's guides for fragments.

Comment: I changed my example to reflect the code you are using for fragment transactions.

Comment: It's really important that you don't call `super.onBackPressed()` in your custom `onBackPressed()` method, UNLESS you're at your Fragment A and want to return to the home screen. That's why I wrapped my super call in an `else` statement.

Comment: Thanks ill try it, ill come back to you if I have a problem :)

Comment: I see I  have to do some modifications to my actual code

Comment: It's work ! But I want to qui the app in the Fragment A and get back to the Fragment A in the other Fragments, how to do ?

Comment: And I have a problem, if i double tap on Back Button it put the Fragment in blank container

Comment: You say that backstack entry county equals 0 its to be on Fragment A, but I have to double tap to quit, if I tap on Back button on Fragment A i have a blank fragment

Comment: The problem is from `fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("name");` when I add it and i push back the app doesn't close it show a blank fragment ive to tap back again to quit

Comment: Can you post your updated code? My first guess is that you're calling `.addToBackStack(String)` in your `onCreate(Bundle)` when you add your initial fragment--which you should not do. But I can't tell without seeing your code.

Comment: I'm calling addToBackStack in `if (fragment != null) {}`, look my edit, sorry to respond later.

Comment: You put `if (fragment != null) {}` in private void `displayView(int position) {} `but if i dot this on line `FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();` i get an error "Unreachable statement"

Comment: The statement is unreachable because (I think) your switch statement includes `default: break;`, meaning it's possible that you never instantiate a fragment. My `displayView(int position)` method was just a copy of *your* method, with one-line modification of adding `addToBackStack(String)`.

Comment: Perfect explanations ! It look work correctely, but I have an another problem I can access to the another fragments from Accueil Fragment, do you know how to do do links like Navigation ? take a look here please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31674571/change-fragment-from-other-fragment-like-navigation-links But thank you for your time ! :)

Comment: Do you know how to do if I intent a new Activity after a Fragment, and go back to Main Activity on the back button and close if i do Back button again ?

Comment: You're going to have to ask a new question

Comment: If you want to see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31826949/back-button-on-the-fragment-activity :)

Answer (score 0):

`onBackPressed()` and `getSupportFragmentManager()` are methods from the Activity class, not Fragment, so you have to implement this on the Activity and not the Fragment.
If you want to implement a particular behaviour just for one fragment you can check what's the current visible fragment and then implement your behaviour. Like this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    MyFragment myFragment =   (MyFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("YOUR_FRAGMENT");
    if (myFragment != null && myFragment.isVisible()) {
       // the code for whatever behaviour you want goes here
    }
    else
       super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Another possible, probably simpler way would be to use some flag in the Activity that you activate when you add the fragment and then read from the `onBackPressed()`.

**EDIT ON RESPONSE TO BENJY'S EDIT**

Notice that you're not exactly using the code I posted. You're using `findFragmentById()` which doesn't apply to every situation and I can't tell if it's right for your code. 
You should use `findFragmentByTag` which applies to any kind of fragment transaction.
Just add a tag to your fragment when you do the transaction, like this:

```
 getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment(), "FRAGMENT_TAG")
                    .commit();
```

Then when you try to get back the Fragment in your `onBackPressed()`, you get it looking for that tag:

```
PlaceholderFragment myFragment = (PlaceholderFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
   .findFragmentByTag("FRAGMENT_TAG");
```

Make this change it has to work.

Comment: @benjy that code was added in your activity class, right ?

Comment: Yes, look up i did your code and add a message to see if it works but no way :)

Comment: @benjy look at my edit. It has to work if you change what I mention. I tried to make sure before posting and it worked for me.

Comment: I agree with jujyfruits that you're better off using `findFragmentByTag()`

Comment: I have replace and you use add:
`getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, fragment, "FRAGMENT_TAG")commit();` and 
`getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment, "FRAGMENT_TAG")commit` are same ?

Comment: @benjy they are not the same, but that shouldn't be a problem for what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I know this too late for answer, but whoever, visits here, might got help with this, I achieved this through below.

if you want to change the fragment keeping the activity on click on device back button, above mentioned all codes will work with removing below line.

```
super.onBackPressed()
```