# Change Fragment from other Fragment like Navigation links

Tags: android, fragment, navigation-drawer

I have a Navigation Drawer (so I use Fragments):

- MainActivity (FragmentActivity)
- Fragment A (Fragment with pictures links for Fragment B, C & D)
- Fragment B (Fragment)
- Fragment C (Fragment)
- Fragment D (Fragment)

My navigation drawer works correctely, but I want to my Fragment A to do links like the menu. Right now, in Fragment A, I call the other Fragments like this:

```
ImageView contact = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.secondBlock);
contact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Fragment fragment = new ContactezNous();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.accueil, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
});
```

But I don't want to use this way, because I have problems finding tags and ids of other Fragments.

I want to know how to change Fragments frome Fragment A by clicking on the link like if I was clicking on the Navigation Drawer links of the Main Activity.

Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentDrawer.FragmentDrawerListener {

    private static String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private FragmentDrawer drawerFragment;

    //Initialisation de l activite avec les donnees necessaires
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        drawerFragment = (FragmentDrawer) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
        drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), mToolbar);
        drawerFragment.setDrawerListener(this);
        // Affichage de la navigation
        displayView(0);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        //Ajout des items
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerItemSelected(View view, int position) {
        displayView(position);
    }

    private void displayView(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        String title = getString(R.string.app_name);
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new Accueil();
                title = getString(R.string.title_accueil);
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new NosOffres();
                title = getString(R.string.title_nosoffres);
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new DemandeGratuite();
                title = getString(R.string.title_demandegratuite);
                break;
            case 3:
                fragment = new ContactezNous();
                title = getString(R.string.title_contact);
                break;
            case 4:
                fragment = new Actualites();
                title = getString(R.string.title_actu);
                break;
            case 5:
                fragment = new MentionsLegales();
                title = getString(R.string.title_mentions);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
            //fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("name");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            // libelle du toolbar
            TextView titlet;
            titlet = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar_title);
            titlet.setText(title);
            titlet.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/GothamBook.ttf"));
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I have a question to clarify what you're asking. You're saying that you want to navigate to another fragment from your `Accueil` fragment, but you don't want to include the fragment transaction code in `Accueil`? Instead, you want it to callback to your `MainActivity`, and have **it** do the transaction?

Comment: @AutonomousApps Yes, because, with links of navigation I can go back to `accueil` but by clicking on the links in accueil it close the app, because it's a transaction, i don't use backstack or something else...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the following common Android fragment pattern:

```
public class Accueil extends Fragment {
    // Your code here...

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        void onInteraction(int id);
    }

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    // ...more code...

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // ...initialize your View...

        ImageView contact = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.secondBlock);
        contact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // This is how you use the listener
                mListener.onInteraction(3);
            }
        });

        // ...more initialization...
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity AppCompatActivity 
        implements FragmentDrawer.FragmentDrawerListener, OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // Your code here...

    // Implement OnFragmentInteractionListener
    @Override
    public void onInteraction(int id) {
        // 'id' would be '3' for your 'ContactezNous' fragment
        displayView(id);
    }
}
```

Comment: But where i specify the OnClickListener of the image in Accueil Fragment ? The four blocks are pictures, and I want them to open fragments like in the navigation

Comment: SO PERFECT !! Thank you !