# android-clear fragment after navigate in navigation component

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

have some problem here.

let's say I have 3 fragment A-B-C. First i navigate from fragment A to B. Then from fragment B i want to navigate to fragment C and clear fragment B from stack. I need to clear it while navigate because i need to make sure the stack become A-C when the user in fragment C, if user click back, user will back to fragment A and there's also a button in fragment C to navigate to fragment B

please help me on this, need some advise to do this or if there any other solution please share it here.

Thanks

Comment: read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31590919/replace-fragment-with-another-on-back-button?rq=1

Comment: @mkm TesterKtl is asking about the Jetpack Navigation Component, the question you posted is not related to it.

Comment: sometimes i wonder why i answer questions that the author doesn't care about tho

Comment: @EpicPandaForce sorry for the late reply I didn't notice the notification for this question. I got the answer already before you post the answer here. But thanks for the answer, I also use this solution for this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is tricky because of Jetpack Navigation's *abysmal* documentation on `Conditional Navigation` which should explain this subject but fails to do so, but the answer is actually quite simple.

All you need is `popUpTo` and `popUpToInclusive`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    app:startDestination="@id/splash_graph"
    tools:ignore="UnusedNavigation">

    <navigation
        android:id="@+id/splash_graph"
        app:startDestination="@id/splash_fragment">

        <action
            android:id="@+id/splash_to_main_graph"
            app:destination="@id/main_graph"
            app:popUpTo="@id/splash_graph"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/splash_fragment"
            android:name="fqn.SplashFragment"
            tools:layout="@layout/splash_fragment" />
    </navigation>

    <navigation
        android:id="@+id/main_graph"
        app:startDestination="@id/fragment_a">

        <action
            android:id="@+id/fragment_a_to_fragment_b"
            app:destination="@id/fragment_b"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_from_left"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_to_right"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_out_to_left"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_in_from_left" />

        <action
            android:id="@+id/fragment_b_to_fragment_c"
            app:destination="@id/fragment_c"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_from_left"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_to_right"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_out_to_left"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_in_from_left"
            app:popUpTo="@id/fragment_b"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />

        <action
            android:id="@+id/fragment_c_to_fragment_b"
            app:destination="@id/fragment_b"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_from_left"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_to_right"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_out_to_left"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_in_from_left"
            app:popUpTo="@id/fragment_c"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment_a"
            android:name="fqn.FragmentA"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_a" />

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment_b"
            android:name="fqn.FragmentB"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_b" />

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment_c"
            android:name="fqn.FragmentC"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_c" />

    </navigation>
</navigation>
```

And then it should be as simple as

```
// FragmentA
findNavController().navigate(R.id.fragment_a_to_fragment_b)

// FragmentB
findNavController().navigate(R.id.fragment_b_to_fragment_c)

// FragmentC
findNavController().navigate(R.id.fragment_c_to_fragment_b)
```

And if you want to go back to FragmentA from FragmentB or FragmentC, you can call `findNavController().popBackStack()`.